# Get data from the byte array

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented, .net

I have a `byte array` and a value defining the type of the data stored in it (`string`, `int`, ...). What is the best way to get this data? I have two options in my mind:

1. Call a method which gives the type of the data and based on that call a method which gives me the correct data.
2. Call a method which returns both - the data (as `object`) and also the type of the data (`DateTime`, `float[]`, ...).

I am not sure if there is something better, nor which one of these methods is better. If
`Type GiveMeDataType();` and e.g. `string GiveMeString();`
or
`MyClass GiveMeData();` with `MyClass { public Type DataType; public object Data; }`

I would like to take the best approach for the best readability and maintainability (add support for additional data types and so on), so I don't think that too many `switch` statements in different parts of code is the best thing to do.

Comment: Can you give me a hint what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Your question is confusing and I'm not sure exactly what you need. Are you aware of [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)? If you are, can you explain why `BitConverter` won't cut it?

Comment: @whatsisname I don't ask how to do the conversion. My question is about the problem that I get some byte array and the type to which I should convert the data. The question is about the problem that I don't know, what type of data I should expect in the rest of the code so I am looking for the best solution how to handle this without over complicating my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a general pattern for this is as follows

```
public interface IData
{
    Type Type {get;set;}
    byte[] Data {get;set;}
}
```

and then many:

```
public interface IDataConverter<T>
{
    T Convert(byte[] data);
    bool CanConvert(Type type);
}
```

So you can make a IDataConverter for whatever types you want, and the Converter has a list of these which it loops through, calling CanConvert. If that returns true, it calls the Convert Function and returns the result

```
class Converter
{
    private List<object> converters;
    public void AddConverter<T>(IDataConverter<T> converter)
    {
        this.converters.Add(converter);
    }
    public T Convert<T>(IData data) where T:class
    {
        var ret = converters
                .Select(i => ((dynamic)i))
                .Where(i => i.CanConvert(data.Type))
                .FirstOrDefault()?
                .Convert(data.Data)
                ;

        return ret as T;
    }
}
```

Edit: as you can see shoehorning in the generic type in there is tricky. You are probably better using the same pattern but just returning object

Comment: I don't see how this eliminates the need for a switch statement.   There are other ways to resolve T at runtime, but they are ... difficult, and you'll probably take a reflection performance hit.

Comment: let me add more code. essentially this is the https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: maybe the generic doesn't work... hmmm you could replace with casting and move it up to the converter method maybe

Comment: I suppose you could maintain a map of Type->Converter

Comment: yeah, I think CanConvert might be better for stuff like list/array/collection you could have a single converter. not 100% sure

Comment: Thanks. To complete your answer, there should be square brackets instead of curly brackets in your method `T Convert(byte[] data);`. The bigger problem is that different generic types in one `List` is more complicated, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/353126/1108200).

Comment: @Artholl improved code. I agree getting the generic to work is hard

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Even if difficulty weren't a problem, I'd say that shifting a compile-time problem to a runtime problem is still a big issue here. Type safety exists for a reason. It's better to ensure inescapable logical cohesion than it is to _hope_ that the developer didn't shoot themselves in the foot in some strange fringe case that they forgot to consider.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do different behavior at run-time depending on the type of data, you won't be able to avoid some kind of switching, although that doesn't have to literally be a switch statement.

For the data itself, the second has the advantage that you can just pass the DynamicData (or whatever you call the Type/object pair) further along to be handled later, but I'd also have a direct method for when the type is known:

```
DynamicData GiveMeData();
T GiveMeData<T>();
```

While a general function to get data can't do more than this, you can change the consumers of the data to handle the different types dynamically.  For example:

```
interface IDataConsumer
{
   IResult Consume(DynamicData data);
}

...

Dictionary<Type,IDataConsumer> consumers = ...;
var data = dataSource.GiveMeData();
var result = consumers[data.DataType].Consume(data);
```

Under the hood that's basically still a switch statement, but one that's a lot easier to add to in future.

And of course if any of the data types share functionality, you can have them implement a common interface and handle them all together.